# Add vector as data.frame element as is

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` consisting of (initially) one observation.
From the original data, I have a list (more specifically, a character vector) which should be appended to the data.frame as a new column and contained in a single element.

Specifically, I have this data.frame:

```
> str(stats.df)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  174 variables:
 $ stat.mineBlock.minecraft.furnace              : num 1
 $ stat.useItem.minecraft.fence_gate             : num 1
 $ stat.useItem.minecraft.stone_brick_stairs     : num 3
 $ stat.killEntity.Sheep                         : num 20
 $ stat.useItem.minecraft.cobblestone            : num 18
```

And I want to add the following:

```
> str(stats.list$achievement.exploreAllBiomes$progress)
  chr [1:6] "Desert" "Extreme Hills" "Ocean" "Extreme Hills Edge" "River" "Hell"
```

So that

```
 > stats.df$achievement.exploreAllBiomes.progress
  [1] "Desert"             "Extreme Hills"      "Ocean"              "Extreme Hills Edge"
  [5] "River"              "Hell"
```

Because `stats.list$achievement.exploreAllBiomes` contains to elements: `value`, which is a numeric, and `progress`, which is a character vector. I want my `stats.df` to contain each of those as separate columns.

My problem is that the data.frame is expanded with additional rows for each element of the character vector, so that each row of the data.frame is identical and only varies in the `achievement.exploreAllBiomes.progress` field, where each row contains one element of said vector.

I have tried the following 3 three things, with and without using `I()`:

```
 stats.df$achievement.exploreAllBiomes.progress        <- I(stats.list$achievement.exploreAllBiomes$progress)
 stats.df$achievement.exploreAllBiomes.progress[1]     <- I(stats.list$achievement.exploreAllBiomes$progress)
 cbind(stats.df, achievement.exploreAllBiomes.progress = I(stats.list$achievement.exploreAllBiomes$progress))
```

Receiving either

```
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "achievement.exploreAllBiomes.progress",  : 
 replacement has 6 rows, data has 1
```

or the duplicate row variant.
I assumed `I()`would do the trick, but it only seems to work when constructing the data.frame from scratch, so I tried constructing `stats.df` with that in mind:

```
stats.df <- data.frame(stats.list[names(stats.list) != "achievement.exploreAllBiomes"],
                     achievement.exploreAllBiomes.value    = stats.list$achievement.exploreAllBiomes$value,
                     achievement.exploreAllBiomes.progress =  I(stats.list$achievement.exploreAllBiomes$progress))
```

But again this produced the duplicate rows.
I know that it is possible for an element in a data.frame to contain a vector or list, so I assume there has to be a fairly easy way to achieve this which I'm probably just not seeing.

Comment: Additionally, for those who were wondering: I am trying to convert Minecraft player statistics (contained in JSON files) to R objects, so that I can easily construct a data.frame with each observation being a player on a server, and then use that for shenanigans. Working with the stats as a list would be possible I guess, but data.frame are much more convenvient to me, especially with plotting in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do that:

```
stats.df <- data.frame(stat.mineBlock.minecraft.furnace = 3, 
                       stat.useItem.minecraft.fence_gate = 5)

stats.list <- c("Desert", "Extreme Hills", "Ocean", "Extreme Hills Edge", "River", "Hell")

stats.df$achievement.exploreAllBiomes.progress <- I(list(stats.list))
stats.df$ach[[1]]

#[1] "Desert"             "Extreme Hills"      "Ocean"             
#[4] "Extreme Hills Edge" "River"              "Hell" 

str(stats.df)
#'data.frame':  1 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ stat.mineBlock.minecraft.furnace     : num 3
# $ stat.useItem.minecraft.fence_gate    : num 5
# $ achievement.exploreAllBiomes.progress:List of 1
#  ..$ : chr  "Desert" "Extreme Hills" "Ocean" "Extreme Hills Edge" ...
#  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much it. I just now realized that of course I would need to subset the `progress` column anyway, meaning that `stats.df$achievement.exploreAllBiomes.progress` would have to be a list of lists anyway, more or less (if that makes any sense). TL;DR This works fine and I'll mark it as accepted in a few hours unless someone posts a pure magic answer (even if I doubt it could be improved).

Comment: @Jemus42 Yeah, I thought to address the inconvenience of that structure in my answer but then decided to cut to the chase. By the way, I have never seen anyone use R for Minecraft; sounds cool!

Comment: It's [marvellous!](http://i.wurstmineberg.de/wurstminestats/). Minecraft was one of the more interesting targets for when I started to learn R back in February :)

Comment: I like it how you present [stats](http://wurstmineberg.de/stats) for your server, it's very neat! One of the most interesting usages of R+shiny+ggplot2 I've ever seen.

Comment: Haha, bummer that statspage has nothing to do with R. [It's all a bunch of javascript](https://github.com/wurstmineberg/wurstmineberg.de), and It's all been written by other server members :)